# Wrong callback in Objective-C when calling SOAP service

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, soap

I have 2 SOAP services that I want to call from an IPad app.

One is used to Log the user in (SecurityASMX), the other is one that returns the current username (SecuredCalls) once logged in.

I can call the SecurityASMX no problem using the following code. The Async call callback is *operation* :

```
- (IBAction) OnButtonClick:(id) sender {

    bindingSecurity = [[SecurityASMXSvc SecurityASMXSoapBinding] initWithAddress:@"http://myserver/Azur.IPADTest.Web.Services/public/Security.asmx"];
    bindingSecurity.logXMLInOut = YES;

    SecurityASMXSvc_Login *requestLogin = [[SecurityASMXSvc_Login alloc] init];
    requestLogin.strUsername = @"test";
    requestLogin.strPassword = @"testpass";

    [bindingSecurity LoginAsyncUsingParameters:requestLogin delegate:self];

    [requestLogin release];

    self.label.text = @"Login in progress";
}

- (void) operation:(SecurityASMXSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(SecurityASMXSoapBindingResponse *)response
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    self.label.text = @"Login Done!";

}
```

This works fine.

However, in the same code file, I have a binding to my second web service to return the username with the following code. The async call callback is *operationSecure* :

```
- (IBAction) OnButtonSecureCallClick:(id) sender {

    bindingSecuredCalls = [[SecureCallsSvc SecureCallsSoapBinding] initWithAddress:@"http://myserver/Azur.IPADTest.Web.Services/private/SecureCalls.asmx"];
    bindingSecuredCalls.logXMLInOut = YES;

    SecureCallsSvc_ReturnUserName *requestReturnUserName = [[SecureCallsSvc_ReturnUserName alloc] init];

    [bindingSecuredCalls ReturnUserNameAsyncUsingParameters:requestReturnUserName delegate:self];

    [requestReturnUserName release];

    self.label.text = @"Get UserName In Progress";
}


- (void) operationSecure:(SecureCallsSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(SecureCallsSoapBindingResponse *)response
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    self.label.text = @"Get Username Done!";

}
```

The problem is that when the call to ReturnUserName returns, the method that gets called is the one for the login (*operation*) and not the one I want (*operationSecure*).

How can I tell my second webservice binding to call the second callback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing would be to check if the API you're using (I assume it's a third party API) allows you to specify the callback method.

If not, you can work with the operation parameter and use isKindOfClass to see what is actually being passed.

```
- (void) operation:(SecurityASMXSoapBindingOperation *)operation completedWithResponse:(SecurityASMXSoapBindingResponse *)response
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    if([operation isKindOfClass:[SecurityASMXSoapBindingOperation class]])
    {
        self.label.text = @"Login Done!";
    }
    else if([operation isKindOfClass:[SecureCallsSoapBindingOperation class]])
    {
        self.label.text = @"Get Username Done!";
    }
}
```

Ideally you'd set the type of operation and response parameters to be the superclass of the respective objects returned.

Comment: Yes it seems that I can pass a delegate to the request but I pass _self_ in both cases. I can't pass _self.operationSecure_ the compiler doesn't let me do that.

Comment: That's the delegate parameter, not the callback method parameter. If the API allows you to change it there will probably be a method that takes a selector and is likely named setCompletedWithResponseSelector or similar. If not, you'll have to follow the answer I gave.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can change the selector (callback method?). I use wsdl2objc for my soap calls. The line where it calls the callback is : `[delegate operation:self completedWithResponse:response];`. Does it look like it can have a different selector?

Comment: It doesn't look like I can change the method name so I'll use your technique... Thanks InsertWittyName! :)